# How can I download the entire Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Is there a way to "get" the whole ethereum blockchain in order to process it locally? For example a link for direct download or via a developer API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. You should install ethereum client https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/
2. Create a folder to store blockchain node.
3. Start geth from cmd with params  `geth --datadir "path to folder from 2" --networkid 1` and to wait synchronization is ended.

Comment: FYI simply running geth without any arguments will launch a full node on main-net. It automatically syncs the entire history into ~/.etherum, the default datadir

Answer (score 0):

Might not be fully what you want but you can get a paid (small fee) verified copy from http://archivenode.net or http://getblockchain.download or http://download.myethereumdatabase.net or http://get.myethereumdatabase.net

If you don’t want to pay for network costs, you also have the option to contribute to the source code of open‐source projects.